# Сокет не видит разрыва TCP-соединения

Tags: c++, сокет

Имеется следующая ситуация.

Есть TCP-соединение на одной машине через `loopback`. Есть два сокета `А` и `Б`, которые переведены в неблокирующий режим. Для сокета `А` вызывается `shutdown(..., SD_BOTH) + close()`, после чего для сокета `Б` вызывается `recv()`, результат которого равен 0.

Является ли ситуация нормальной? Мне казалось, что в сценарии сокет `Б` должен обнаружить закрытие канала, в результате чего последующие вызовы `recv()` должны возвращать не 0.

Comment: возврат 0 при вызове recv, если с той стороны закрыли сокет - норма.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Является ли ситуация нормальной?

Да, всё так и должно быть, POSIX требует того, что при корректном закрытии соединения второй стороной, если в сокете нет больше других сообщений, [`recv()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html) должен возвращать `0`. Именно это стоит использовать в качестве индикации завершения соединения.

На практике `0` может возвращаться и в других случаях (см. документацию своей системы для своего протокола), например:

- Получена датаграмма нулевой длины (не относится к TCP)
- В вызове `recv` был передан буфер нулевой длины

Comment: Это же относится и к неблокирующим сокетам?

Comment: @MGNeo, да. блокирующий сокет или нет на это ни как не влияет... если что, то неблокирующий сокет, если ему нечего читать, возращает `-1` и устанавливает ошибку `EAGAIN`.

Comment: вы в этом уверены? Я что-то ничего подобного найти в документации не могу, может, я не туда смотрю?

Comment: В качестве индикации завершения соединения возврат 0 использовать как раз не стоит, так как это может происходить и в других случаях.

Comment: @MGNeo, дык в POSIX же по ссылке: *If no messages are available to be received and the peer has performed an orderly shutdown, recv() shall return 0.*... ИМХО можно смело считать, что все реализации BSD-сокетов этому удовлетворяют...

Comment: @user7860670, и в каких невырожденных ситуациях это возможно? на какой ОС? что тогда предлагаешь использовать вместо этого (AFAIK другого интерфейса нет, но вдруг я заблуждаюсь)?

Comment: @user7860670, почитайте [man read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)

Comment: По идее это возможно при нормальной работе. На обычной бубунте 18.04. Вместо этого стоит опираться на данные прикладного протокола.

Comment: @user7860670, нет, ты не прав... по крайней мере для TCP и других SOCK_STREAM-сокетов (ко всякой экзотике вроде `sctp` и других `SOCK_SEQPACKET`/`SOCK_RDM` у меня тоже вопросы)... на протокол полагаться тоже нельзя: во-первых, вторая сторона может неожиданно закрыть соединение и если игнорировать возврат `0` и продолжить чтение как обычно, то ты просто окажешься в бесконечном цикле, а, во-вторых, многие прикладные протоколы полагаются в этом на транспортный уровень...